# Como separar una linea por columnas con determinado tamaño

Tags: excel, notepad++

Tengo un archivo de txt, el cual contiene múltiples lineas con el mismo tamaño, tengo un archivo de interpretación de el tamaño y contiene esa columna.

Ejemplo.

Columna 1 tiene tamaño 7.

Columna 2 tiene tamaño 5.

Columna 3 tiene tamaño 6.

*Ejemplo linea*
**ADF123400000F45556**

*Ejemplo esperada*
**ADF1234 | 00000 | F45556**

Alguna forma de hacerlo o algun plugin que me ayude.

Comment: ¿El archivo de interpretación es tal cual en tu ejemplo? ¿Solo necesitas separarlos con palote (|)? ¿Solo quieres usar Excel o Notepad++? ¿Podrías usar PowerShell?

Comment: La interpretación es similar al ejemplo pero con mas columnas de tamaño, no necesariamente podría ser cualquier separador, por practico tome en cuenta Excel y Notepad++, pero cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida (ej. PowerShell ).

Comment: Agregué una respuesta considerando en `PowerShell`, ¿Te funcionó o tuviste algún inconveniente?

Answer (score 1):

Usando **PowerShell**, considerando lo siguiente:

Archivo **interpretador.txt**:

> ```
> Columna 1 tiene tamaño 7.
> Columna 2 tiene tamaño 5.
> Columna 3 tiene tamaño 6.
> ```

Archivo **contenido.txt**:

> ```
> ADF123400000F45556
> ABC432100000F35556
> ```

Ejecutas los comandos en PowerShell:

```
$rutaArchivoInterpretador = "C:\Users\davlio\Desktop\interpretador.txt"
$rutaArchivoContenido  = "C:\Users\davlio\Desktop\contenido.txt"
$rutaArchivoResultado  = "C:\Users\davlio\Desktop\resultado.txt"

Get-Content $rutaArchivoContenido | % {
    $contenidoFila = "$_"
    $indice = 0
    $nuevoContenido = ""

    Get-Content $rutaArchivoInterpretador | % {
        $contenidoInterpretador = "$_"
        $longitudColumna = [int]($contenidoInterpretador.Substring(23) -replace ".$")

        $nuevoContenido = $nuevoContenido + $contenidoFila.Substring($indice, $longitudColumna) + "|"

        $indice = $indice + $longitudColumna
    }

    $nuevoContenido -replace ".$" | Out-File -Append $rutaArchivoResultado
}
```

Donde las variables:

- `$rutaArchivoInterpretador`: Almacena la ruta del archivo interpretador
- `$rutaArchivoContenido`: Almacena la ruta del archivo contenido
- `$rutaArchivoResultado`: Almacena la ruta donde se creará el consolidado

Obtendrás:

Archivo **resultado.txt**:

> ```
> ADF1234|00000|F45556
> ABC4321|00000|F35556
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Con notepad++:

1. Control+H
2. Buscar: `^(.{7})(.{5})(.{6})` (Los números que ves (7,5,6) son los tamaños de las columnas. Utiliza los valores de tu archivo interpretador.txt)
3. Reemplazar con: `\1|\2|\3`
4. Opciones: Modo búsqueda = Expresión regular; **no** marcar la opción ". se ajusta a línea"